# (Wpf) C# start process open URL via logged in user

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, arguments

Hi I'm trying to open URL via logged in user because I'm running my app with domain administrator and I need the URL open by the user.

So far all I find out is that basically it cannot be doen and there is why:
If I use `process.start(URL)` and the `iexplore` is already open by the local user it opens a new tab like the user's.
But if the `iexplore` is not open then it opens a new window with the admin properties.

So I tried the next best thing: `Process.start("explorer.exe",URL)`.
It work perfectly but my URL contains equal sign (`=`) so it opens the URL in `iexplore` but only until the equal sign (without the URL's query string).

For example:

My original URL `http://www.somewebsite.com/myvalue=username`

What the process opened `http://www.somewebsite.com/myvalue`

As a result I get an error from the website.

I use .net 4.5 if that makes a difference.
(btw, impersonate is too complicated for me.. I need to user it with simple button)

Answer (score 0):

it is cross paging variable passing mechanism via URL  , if you pass the username then try instead to use session cross paging mechanism
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw(v=vs.90).aspx 
you can try the URLencoder and URLdecoder too
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I let you know if that works.. I just replace it manually because it is the same URL every time..

Comment: The %3D is not working... The webpage just read them as %3D and not as equal sign(=)..

Comment: because it is parameters syntax , use session variable to to send the username